# Making a script loop on changes to json

Tags: javascript, eventsource

I think I posted far too lengthy of a question... To slim it a bit I will summarize.

I have a javascript file here:

```
let eventSource = new EventSource('selectedSystemState-script.php');

eventSource.addEventListener("selectedSystemStateResultsMessage", function(event) {
  let data = JSON.parse(event.data);
  let listElements = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (let i = 0; i < listElements.length; i++) {
    let selectedSystemStateResults = listElements[i].textContent;
    if (!data.includes(selectedSystemStateResults)) {
      listElements[i].style.color = "red";
    }
  }
});
```

The if statement at the end changes the text to red upon updates. Red colors do not help me, imagine a flight information display just showing a bunch of red text for every change but no tangible info LOL...I would rather just loop it back to the start so that it displays the freshly parsed data and rebuilds the listElements. How should that last statement be modified to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

That feeling when you are so proud at figuring out something on your own....

I replaced

```
listElements[i].style.color = "red";
```

with

```
document.location.reload()
```

Hopefully that was the correct way to do it, seems to be working.